# BufferedReader readLine() waiting for ever reading from Process inputStream

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, runtime.exec, inputstreamreader

I am reading the standardOutput from a Process using the common code to do it:

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gradlew assembleRelease", null , new File(this.workDir));            
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;     
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            standardOutput.writeln(line);
        }
        input.close();
```

It worked perfectly until now. It stores the output into a txt file with my function standardOutput.writeln(line). Recently I updated my server to compile with gradle 2.8 and now i'm having a very serious problem. When gradle fails, input.readLine() function is being waiting for ever. I don't understand why. It is stuck at that line.  I can't find any explanation. I thought that it can be because readLine is waiting for a /n to stop reading and there is a possibility that new gradle output is having some issues with this but i'm not sure if that is the problem.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: *"When gradle fails"* and it tells you that in the standard output stream, not the error stream?

Comment: it is being locked in this, i'm trying to read the errorStream after this code, but never reach that code

Answer (score 0):

The solution finally was to read standard output and error output in two separated threads, the process was blocking itself trying to write in error output while reading standard output...